# What do array initialisers return?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What do array initialisers such as `{ 'a', 'b', 'c' }` return? My understanding is that using an initialiser allocates contiguous memory blocks and return the address to the first block.

The following code doesn't work:

```
char *char_ptr_1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
```

On the other hand, this is seems to work fine:

```
char char_array[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
char *char_ptr_2 = char_array;
```

`char_array` stores the address to the first memory block which explains why I am able to assign the value of `char_array` to `chat_ptr_2`. Does C convert the value returned by the initialiser to something which can be stored in a pointer?

I did look online and and found a couple of answers which talked about the difference between arrays and pointers but they didn't help me.

Comment: you want Compound literals in C99. E.g. `char *char_ptr_2 = (char[]){ 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };`

Comment: Still, the initializer list of a compound literal follows the same rules as any other initializer list. The compound literal just allocates an anonymous chunk of data on the stack. So it's the same thing as declaring an array and then assign a pointer to point at that array.

Comment: You could say `char *char_ptr_1 = "abc";`. However, GCC reports it as deprecated without a `const` modifier.  Presumably that is because the compiler is not required to create a unique array for each string literal occurrence.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Initializers do not *return* anything per se. They give the compiler directions as to what to put into the item being declared - in this case, they tell the compiler what to put into elements of an array.

That is why you cannot assign an initializer to a pointer: an array initializer needs to be paired with an array to make sense to the compiler.

A pointer can be initialized with a pointer expression. That is why the initialization in your

```
char *char_ptr_2 = char_array;
```

declaration works: the compiler converts `char_array` to a pointer, and initializes `char_ptr_2` with it.

Answer (score 6):

it's called array initializer, because it initalizes an array and not a pointer.

It's simply C syntax, why the pointer option is not allowed.

Answer (score 4):

They are *array initializers*, not normal expressions that have a value. I. e., an array initializer can *only* be used to initialize an array. It is a special bit of syntax for a specific use, end of the story.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really "return" anything, it's parsed compile time and an array is created. A pointer needs to point to something, you cannot assign it a direct value. So you first need the array, and then your pointer can point to it.